# Did Klingons develop Gunpowder Weapons?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-the-original-series

Seeing the **Star Trek** TOS episode Season 2 Episode 19, "*A Private Little War*", it seems to imply that chemical propellant firearms are a common technological invention of young civilizations. The plot revolves around Klingons arming one village with flintlock smooth bore long gun, with a promise to upgrade to rifled long guns. At one point, the bridge crew have an (unwanted) discussion about the speed of technological advancement among different species.

Does this mean Klingons also developed the same weapons as humans, common gunpowder small arms?

Comment: I doubt if it's covered in the canon literature but it seems likely. Even if they didn't, they would still have been **aware** of them as they expanded the Empire from gathered knowledge.

Comment: Shakespeare mentioned guns a few times, and you have not experienced Shakespeare until you have read him in the original Klingon [;)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102975/quotes?item=qt0423622)

Comment: This is meta-, I suppose, but keep in mind that Klingons are just humans, metaphorically, and the Soviets in particular. But it's a common sci-fi trope to assume that civilizations advance along particular lines, if for no other reason than it makes it an alien civ more comprehensible to the audience. Just like alien biology will mirror humans and, in the case of a lot of scifi, aliens will speak English. It's goofy, perhaps, but the author wants to focus on what he wants to focus on, not "accuracy".

Comment: If we consider the implications of TNG: 'The Chase', the reason the various humanoid species in the Alpha Quadrant all (potentially) developed gunpowder weapons is because they all have the same common ancestor, which may have guided their evolution along the same path.